# Pdf for distance between two uniform random points in a circle

Tags: circles, uniform-distribution

This is my first post in the group and I would be very thankful for any help. I am trying to develop a probability distribution for a performance analysis in my thesis. I am trying to look in to literature which provides the probability distribution for distance between two random points in a unit circle.

I would try to explain the problem. Suppose we have a point X and we have point x1 in the unit circle C1 which contains X. There is another unit circle X2 right next to the circle X1. There is a point x2 in the unit circle X2. Let d1 be the distance between X and x1 and d2 be the distance between X and x2. All the points are distributed within respective circles with random distribution. I want to know the probability distribution for d1/d2. Has anyone worked with a similar problem or anybody can direct me towards any literature.

Thank you so much for the help. 
Cheers, 
Waqas

Comment: By "the unit circle $C_1$ which contains $X$" do you mean that $X$ is the center of $C_1$?

Comment: What are the centers of the circles?

Answer (score 2):

Where is your problem? Google is your friend!

If you google the words:

*distance random points in circles*

the first hit gives you the book:
*An introduction to geometrical probability*  by A.M. Mathai.

To find in Google:

http://books.google.de/books/about/An_Introduction_to_Geometrical_Probabili.html?id=FV6XncZgfcwC&redir_esc=y

If you look into the book in Google preview,
on page 217 you find a chapter treating your problem.

Maybe you can read it yourself ;-)!

Ciao

Karl

Comment: Hi Karl. Thank you so much for the link. Unfortunately, the relevant chapter is not available for reading and I am unable to find it in library of my own uni. I hope I can get a similar book or this book to read through and get the solution. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Hi Waqas, did you try this link, there is page 217-9:<http://books.google.de/books?id=FV6XncZgfcwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false>

Comment: I  have tried to open the link. It is probably from the german version of google but it says that from 77-555 it is not available for reading. I am trying to search it to suggest to my supervisor if I could buy it but I can not find any link as of yet to get it. I hope I can find the book as it clearly would help me a great deal.

Comment: Sorry that it doesn't work. Amazon gives also a preview, not these pages, but at least the bibliography. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Hi. I got the pages of the book from my library. The pdf involves an integral of which I am finding hard to solve. Could you help. I have posted the integral here

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941079/solution-to-the-integral

Comment: It turns out the the Mathai book has been added to researchgate by the author.  So you can get a PDF of the entire thing   [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264872771_An_Introduction_to_Geometrical_Probability_Distributional_Aspects_with_Applications)